CLARITY with ANGULAR : Modal not opening due to @fademove animation
Describe the bug
I'm trying to open a modal using "clr-modal" component, but I'm faced issue telling:
core.mjs:6620 ERROR Error: NG05105: Unexpected synthetic listener @fadeMove.done found. Please make sure that:
  - Either BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule are imported in your application.
  - There is corresponding configuration for the animation named @fadeMove.done defined in the animations field of the @Component` decorator (see https://angular.io/api/core/Component#animations).


How to reproduce
When I click on the button to switch the boolean attribute to true, the error appears and no modal is shown.
my-component.html

<div class="clr-row clr-justify-content-end">
    <div class="clr-col-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon" aria-label="home" (click)="deleteGroupModalOpen = true">
            <cds-icon shape="plus-circle"></cds-icon>
            Add
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clr-row">
        <div *ngFor="let group of kcmGroups" class="clr-col-lg-3 clr-col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="clr-row">
                        <div class="clr-col clr-align-self-start">
                            <a [ngClass]="getLabelStyle(group.color)">Group: {{ group.name }}</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clr-col clr-align-self-end">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm" aria-label="home">
                                <cds-icon shape="pencil"></cds-icon>
                              </button>
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-sm btn-danger" aria-label="home" >
                                <cds-icon shape="trash"></cds-icon>
                              </button>

                              
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-success" aria-label="settings">
                        <cds-icon shape="deploy"></cds-icon>
                        Enter
                      </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <clr-modal [(clrModalOpen)]="deleteGroupModalOpen">
            <h3 class="modal-title">I have a nice title</h3>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>But not much to say...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline" (click)="deleteGroupModalOpen = false">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteGroupModalOpen = false">Ok</button>
            </div>
          </clr-modal>
          
</div>

app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { ClarityModule } from "@clr/angular";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ClarityModule,
  ],
  declarations: [  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }

main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));


package.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "kcm-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/kcm-angular",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/@cds/core/global.min.css",
              "node_modules/@cds/core/styles/theme.dark.min.css",
              "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "kcm-angular:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "kcm-angular:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Versions
Clarity version:

[x] v17.2.0

Framework version:
Angular 18.0.4
Device:

OS: UBUNTU 20.04
Browser chrome


stackblit link: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/ahmedtoumi/test-clarity-modal

I got the answer here :https://github.com/vmware-clarity/ng-clarity/issues/1453

I see the issue now. The AppModule where you import BrowserAnimationsModule is not actually used because you are bootstrapping the AppComponent directly. You need to add provideAnimations() in appConfig. You can delete the AppModule because it is not needed when using standalone components.

